# Chart x axis displays in timestamp instead of dates Chart.js

Tags: javascript, web, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am doing a graph of a json with chart js. Even if I set the formatted to date I still get timestamp. I hope someone can help me. BTW the data is being retrieved from firebase. I attach the code I am using.

Thanks in advance.

**Output:**
[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
            var currentDate= val.date; //Extracting the date value in dd/mm/yyyy format from the mentioned text box
```

I get the data from firebase

```
                     //Printing the extracted date value before making the change
                    var newDate = currentDate.split('/'); //Splitting the extracted date value using the delimiter /, which is the seperator used in the date value         
                    currentDate = newDate[1] + "/" + newDate[0] + "/" + newDate[2];//Constructing a new date value (string) using the splitted values.
```

I format it to MMDDYYYY

```
var dateObject = new Date(currentDate);
```

Then it is changed to a date data type

```
var data_point={
  x:dateObject,
  y:parseFloat(val.sa_quantity)
};
datapoints.push(data_point);
```

I add all the data changed to an array that is used to plot the data

```
var chartData = [];
      var ctxR = document.getElementById("data_chart").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctxR, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
          labels:dates,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Predicted Sales($)',
            data: datapoints
          }]
        },
        responsive: true,
            title:{
                display: true,
                text:"Chart.js Time Scale"
            },
            scales:{
                xAxes: [{
                  type: 'time',
                  time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                      'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
                      'second': 'MMM DD',
                      'minute': 'MMM DD',
                      'hour': 'MMM DD',
                      'day': 'MMM DD',
                      'week': 'MMM DD',
                      'month': 'MMM DD',
                      'quarter': 'MMM DD',
                      'year': 'MMM DD',
                    },
                    round: 'day',
                    unit: 'day',
                  }
                }]
            }
        });
        myChart.update();
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, could you share you working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the display format. chart.js likes unix, people like date strings.
You should add something like this function to display your dates:

```
function getTimeString(date) {
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}
```

Whenever I work with a time-scale in chart.js I add moment.js because it's much more powerful. But it can be kind of an overkill for webapps.

Comment: how do you implement this? I have exact same issue